# trying to run arbitrary commands and parse their output

Tags: c

here is part of code

```
 scanf("%[^\n]%*c",command);      
int pid;    
 pid=fork();    
 if (pid == 0) {    
 // Child process    
char *argv[]={command ,NULL};    
execvp(argv[0], argv);    
exit (0);    
  }
```

When I give as input `ls` I want as output

```
1      copy of mysh1.c     mysh1.c  mysh3.c  mysh.c    New Folder
a.out  helpmanual.desktop  mysh2.c  mysh4.c  New File
```

and when i give `ls -l /tmp`
i'm waiting

```
    total 12   
-rw------- 1 antre antre 0 Nov 4 17:31 config-err-KT9sEZ     
drwx------ 2 antre antre 4096 Nov 4 19:21 mozilla_antre0        
drwx------ 2 antre antre 4096 Jan 1 1970 orbit-antre     
drwx------ 2 antre antre 4096 Nov 4 17:31 ssh-HaOFtKdeIQnQ     `
```

but i take:
`1      copy of mysh1.c    mysh1.c  mysh3.c  mysh.c    New Folder

    a.out  helpmanual.desktop  mysh2.c  mysh4.c  New File`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: with this programme i always take as output    
`    1      copy of mysh1.c     mysh1.c  mysh3.c  mysh.c    New Folder
     a.out  helpmanual.desktop  mysh2.c  mysh4.c  New File`
  
and with the input ls -l /tmp

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you completly, but it seems you want to pass `ls -l /tmp` to your program, which should then execute exactly this, but your program instead executes `ls` without the arguments. The reason for that might be that you pass the complete command in `argv[0]`, you might have to split the arguments into the `argv` array. Another option would be to use [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

Comment: could you give a code example please  (not with system )

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to parse the output of `ls -l` in a C program for some reason.

That's unlikely to be the “right” thing to do. The usual mechanism is to use `opendir` and `readdir` to read the directory file, directly.

If you have some truly strange situation in which you cannot `opendir` (the only case that comes to mind is if you're running `ls` on a remote system, eg, over `ssh`), there is a mode in GNU `ls` specifically for producing an output record format that can be parsed by another program.

From the GNU coreutils `info`:

### 10.1.2 What information is listed

```
‘-D’
‘--dired’
```

With the long listing (‘-l’) format, print an additional line after
the main output:

```
      //DIRED// BEG1 END1 BEG2 END2 ...
```

The BEGN and ENDN are unsigned integers that record the byte
     position of the beginning and end of each file name in the output.
     This makes it easy for Emacs to find the names, even when they
     contain unusual characters such as space or newline, without fancy
     searching.

If directories are being listed recursively (‘-R’), output a
     similar line with offsets for each subdirectory name:

```
      //SUBDIRED// BEG1 END1 ...
```

Finally, output a line of the form:

```
      //DIRED-OPTIONS// --quoting-style=WORD
```

where WORD is the quoting style (*note `Formatting the file
     names::`).

Here is an actual example:

```
      $ mkdir -p a/sub/deeper a/sub2
      $ touch a/f1 a/f2
      $ touch a/sub/deeper/file
      $ ls -gloRF --dired a
        a:
        total 8
        -rw-r--r-- 1    0 Jun 10 12:27 f1
        -rw-r--r-- 1    0 Jun 10 12:27 f2
        drwxr-xr-x 3 4096 Jun 10 12:27 sub/
        drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Jun 10 12:27 sub2/

        a/sub:
        total 4
        drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Jun 10 12:27 deeper/

        a/sub/deeper:
        total 0
        -rw-r--r-- 1 0 Jun 10 12:27 file

        a/sub2:
        total 0
      //DIRED// 48 50 84 86 120 123 158 162 217 223 282 286
      //SUBDIRED// 2 3 167 172 228 240 290 296
      //DIRED-OPTIONS// --quoting-style=literal
```

Note that the pairs of offsets on the ‘//DIRED//’ line above
     delimit these names: ‘f1’, ‘f2’, ‘sub’, ‘sub2’, ‘deeper’, ‘file’.
     The offsets on the ‘//SUBDIRED//’ line delimit the following
     directory names: ‘a’, ‘a/sub’, ‘a/sub/deeper’, ‘a/sub2’.

Here is an example of how to extract the fifth entry name,
     ‘deeper’, corresponding to the pair of offsets, 222 and 228:

```
      $ ls -gloRF --dired a > out
      $ dd bs=1 skip=222 count=6 < out 2>/dev/null; echo
      deeper
```

Note that although the listing above includes a trailing slash for
     the ‘deeper’ entry, the offsets select the name without the
     trailing slash.  However, if you invoke ‘ls’ with ‘--dired’ along
     with an option like ‘--escape’ (aka ‘-b’) and operate on a file
     whose name contains special characters, notice that the backslash
     *is* included:

```
      $ touch 'a b'
      $ ls -blog --dired 'a b'
        -rw-r--r-- 1 0 Jun 10 12:28 a\ b
      //DIRED// 30 34
      //DIRED-OPTIONS// --quoting-style=escape
```

If you use a quoting style that adds quote marks (e.g.,
     ‘--quoting-style=c’), then the offsets include the quote marks.  So
     beware that the user may select the quoting style via the
     environment variable ‘QUOTING_STYLE’.  Hence, applications using
     ‘--dired’ should either specify an explicit
     ‘--quoting-style=literal’ option (aka ‘-N’ or ‘--literal’) on the
     command line, or else be prepared to parse the escaped names.

Comment: i just want an executable programme witch read the name of a programme and his parameters and then run it

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different thing than your question. Are you trying to parse `ls -l` or trying to run arbitrary commands and parse their output?

Comment: can you help me ,please

Comment: I think you need to re-write the question entirely to describe what you're trying to do, then. I've answered the question you've asked as best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

i just only needed to use `strtok`